# How do computers on the internet locate each other using IP addresses?

Tags: networking, router, ip, isp

Given an IP address, how do ISPs know how to find the node assigned that IP? Is there a central server, or several distributed servers, somewhere that hold information on all allocated IPs?

After getting information on the network node assigned the IP how do they know how to connect to it? In simple terms, how do they know what cable path to take to reach that IP.

When I do an IP location lookup where does the data I get come from?

Comment: Try searching on Google for 'Routing 101' or similar.

Comment: Routers route using something called a "routing table".  Within an organization, routing protocols like OSPF and RIP may be used to automate updates to the routing table.  Between ISPs, I would tend to expect that the routing protocol would be the Border Gateway Protocol, abbreviated BGP.  I believe a thorough answer is likely to have a discussion involving the terms BGP and ASN.

Answer (score 5):

Every router, or "hop" has a routing table, that says for network segment X.X.X.X, go out through interface Y.  If it doesn't have any information on that network segment, there is a route of last resort, more commonly known as the default gateway, that directs again out a particular interface to the next router in the chain.

At every router, this decision is repeated.  For most ISPs you're basically hitting a few larger and larger infrastructure routers through default gateways until you get to one of the backbone routers.  These will usually have interchange routes to other ISPs, or other backbone networks, and your traffic is handed off to each using much the same routing decisions as it always had.  Some will use very general routing information (anything that matches 200.*.*.* and up that way), some will collate much more specific information.  Eventually it reaches the ISP or provider that coordinates the network you want, and filter back down until it hits where you addressed it.

All of this is part and parcel of IP protocol, which determines not only which addresses are usable where, but how to segment and transit several different networks in such a fashion.  Your computer never knows exactly the route to take, but breaks traffic up into packets, and the routers know how to handle the packets.

There are many other protocols built just to distribute routing information in an efficient manner, other protocols your PCs coordinate to make sure nothing gets lost, and the tech infrastructure to do it all in speedy fashion is mind-boggling.  Still, the basic principle is held up at most points between A and B.

Comment: BGP would be worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 0):

It would take a while to fully understand the intricate design of the Internet or know how computer networks works. 
I have found a short article explaining on [how do computers connect to each other over the Internet](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001358.htm).

> If you have a home computer network, the computers are also using TCP/IP to connect to each other. This protocol allows each computer to "see" the other computers on the network and share files between them and is what makes it possible for a printer to be shared on a network. When computers connect to each other on the same network, it is called a local area network, or LAN. When multiple networks are connected to each other, it is called a wide area network, or WAN. With this type of network, your home has a network router that connects to your ISP. The router is given the IP address for your connection to the Internet and then assigns local IP addresses to each device in your network. These local addresses are often 192.168.1.2-255. When accessing a local computer in your own network, your router sends your TCP/IP packets between the local IP addresses. However, when you want to connect to the Internet your router communicates to the Internet with the IP address assigned to it from the ISP. This is why when on the Internet your IP address is not a 192.168.x.x address.
>
> When requesting information from a web page, such as Computer Hope you enter a URL that is easy to understand and remember. For your computer to access the computer containing the pages that URL must be converted into an IP address, this is done with DNS. Once DNS has converted the URL into an IP address the routers on the Internet will know how to route your TCP/IP packet. Below is a graphic illustration of everything explained above to help better illustrate the process of your computer communicating with another computer on the Internet.

Comment: That ComputerHope post is a _bit_ too vague for this question; literally the only part that even tries to answer it is "and the packet travels over multiple routers until it reaches that address"...

Comment: @grawity at least it "tries" to answer knowing that the concept of routing in computer networking is such a topic.